# VMSku detail of each Vm under given resource group in to excel sheet

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

Am trying to get VM sku details with rest of the parameter using azure powershell task in a azure devops pipeline. but instead of vmsku details , excel sheet showing "Microsoft.Azure.management.Compute.Models.HardwareProfile" in  all columns of excel sheet. What am i doing wrong here. Am expecting to get details like "Standard_m32ls "

Note: grep-wildcard variable alue will passed through pipeline

```
report = @()
$niclist = Get-AZNetworkInterface | Where-Object {$_ResourceGroupName -eq '*$(grp-wildcard)' } |Select-Object
$VM =Get-AzVm -Status | Where-Object {$_ResourceGroupName -eq '*$(grp-wildcard) '} |Select-Object
$power= $VM.powerstate
$vms = Get-AzVM | Where-Object {$_ResourceGroupName -eq '*$(grp-wildcard) '} |Select-Object

foreach($nic in $niclist){
Array = "" |Select-Object ResourceGroupName,ServerHostname,VMstatus,VMSKU
$Array.ResourceGroupName = $nic.ResourceGroupName
$Array.ServerHostName =$nic.VirtualMachine.Id
$Array.VMstate = $power[0]
$Array.VMSKU = $vms.HardwareProfile.VmSize[0]
}
$report+=$Array
$report |Format-Table ResourceGroupName,ServerHostname,VMstatus,VMSKU
$report | Export-Csv -NTI -path "$(BuildArtifactStagingDirectory)/test.csv"
```

Comment: Are you wanting all available SKUs or the SKU of the single VM?  If your wanting all available skus check this out?  
http://www.thatlazyadmin.com/how-to-list-available-azure-vm-images-using-powershell/  

Technically you could use the data from that with the command Get-AzLocation to get all the locations.  

With that you could create a loop and use an array to create an array of all the ski options.  If you know what location you want you could limit it to just a few locations

Comment: I need to get SKU detail of each Vm under specified resource group

Comment: The size / sku of the VM is available as a property on `$vms.HardwareProfile.VmSize`.

Comment: @pijemcolu i tired $vms.HardwareProfile.VmSize as well. but getting same in to excel

Comment: Why no just use Get-AzVm.  You have access to the SKu from that and it will list all the VMS.  You could use Get-AzVm | Select-Object Name, ResourceGroupName, @{N="VmSize"; E={$_.HardwareProfile.VmSize}}  That will return an object with the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is getting the same data as you are trying to do:

```
$rgName = ""
$vms = Get-AzVM -Status | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $rgName }

$report = @()
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    $vmResult = @{
        ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
        ServerHostName = $vm.Id
        VmStatus = $vm.Powerstate
        VmSku = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
    }
    $report += $vmResult
}

$report | Export-Csv -Path "$(BuildArtifactStagingDirectory)/test.csv"
```

Comment: I have tried ur script. Its giving same SKU value for all VMs, which is incorrect. I have updated my question with latest changes

Comment: Yep. In your updated script also the powerstatus is the same for all VMs because of wrongly iterating. What I've posted withholds the report data structure as well as iterates correctly.

Answer (score 0):

this looks to be getting what you need

```bsh
$rgName = ""
$report = @()
Get-AzVm -Status | Select-Object @{N="ServerHostName"; E={$_.VmId}}, Name, ResourceGroupName, @{N="VmSku"; E={$_.HardwareProfile.VmSize}}, @{N="VmStatus"; E={$_.Powerstate}} | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $rgName } | ForEach-Object $vm { 

    $report += $vm
}
$report | Export-Csv -Path "$(BuildArtifactStagingDirectory)/test.csv"
```